# Spring boot junit test @JpaDataTest not working due to missing dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to write a test using my actual configuration.

In the normal spring context, I'm loading the dataSource using a `@Autowired` service that decrypts the database password from the properties.

It looks like this

```
@Configuration
public class DataBaseConfig {

    @Value("${swat.datasource.url}")
    private String dbURL;

    @Value("${swat.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverName;

    @Value("${swat.datasource.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${swat.datasource.password}")
    private String hashedPassword;

    @Autowired
    EncryptionService encryptionService;

    @Bean
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        String password = encryptionService.decriptPassword(hashedPassword);
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().url(dbURL).driverClassName(driverName).username(userName).password(password).build();
    }
```

im now trying to run a test using @JpaDataTest (not the @SpringBootTest)
doing the following

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)
@Import(DataBaseConfig.class)
@TestPropertySource(value = "file:./executor.properties")
public class NewDeviceTest {
    
    @Autowired
    NewDeviceService newDeviceService;
    
    @Test
    public void loadNewDevices() {
        List<NewDevice> devices = newDeviceService.findAll();
        assertEquals(1, devices.size());
        assertTrue(devices.get(0).isNew());
    }

}
```

im getting a problem since the EncryptionService in the DataBaseConfig cannot be resolved
how do i tell the Test to first load this

i tried

```
@ComponentScan("com.wisemon.compliance.executor.service")
```

but it loads all the components and some of them have a behaviour that i dont want in my test (load initial db data... scheduling etc)

Comment: Perhaps you can use this annotation @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)

Comment: no... i get the same error: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxxx.compliance.executor.dao.EncryptionService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Comment: `@Import(DataBaseConfig.class)` you are only loading one class thats why.

Comment: @tomas i already import database config, but this config needs EncryptionService

Comment: That error you mentioned is due to need to add a bean name in order to qualify what bean you need to use so @Bean(name = firstEncryptionService") then you use it    @Autowired @Qualifier("firstEncryptionService") where it is causing this issue